# Plotting PCA, autoplot() doesn't separate colors by group variable

Tags: r, ggplot2, pca

I am using ggplot2 package and ggfortify to plot PCA results. The last column of my data matrix is a column of four different factors. Name of the column is 'group'. 
It is like:

```
group
a
b
a
c
d
```

The code I used is:

> autoplot(prcomp(df), data = mydata, colour = "group",frame=T)

However, in the plot generated, the groups of different points are not separated by color.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d9IQA.png)

Any advices? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, the grouping variable need to be formatted as a Factor, instead of a column of characters.